# How to retrieve a struct in window_proc function in WM_COMMAND msg?

Tags: rust, windows-rs

I'm trying to write a simple windows app in rust with windows-rs crate. I'd like to have a state wrapped in Counter struct and pass it to window_proc function. It is successful to retrieve the pointer and store it by GWLP_USERDATA index. My question is that why it increases in WM_CREATE msg without error, but does not work in WM_COMMAND msg?

```rust
struct Counter {
    counter: i32
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let lparam: *mut Counter = Box::leak(Box::new(Counter{
        counter: 1
    }));

    unsafe {
        let mut instance = Default::default();
        GetModuleHandleExW(0, None, &mut instance)?;

        let wnd_class = WNDCLASSEXW {
           // ... ...
        };

        let atom = RegisterClassExW(&wnd_class);
        debug_assert!(atom != 0);

        let hwnd = CreateWindowExW(
            // ... ...
            Some(lparam as *mut c_void),
        );

        // ... ...
    }
}

fn increase_and_print(parent: HWND) {
    unsafe {
        let ptr = GetWindowLongPtrW(parent, GWLP_USERDATA);
        println!("GetWindowLongPtrW: {}", ptr);

        let ptr = GetWindowLongPtrW(parent, GWLP_USERDATA) as *mut Box<Counter>;
        debug_assert!(!ptr.is_null());
        let c =  &mut *ptr;
        c.counter += 1;
        println!("counter: {}", c.counter);
    }
}

extern "system" fn window_proc(hwnd: HWND, msg: u32, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT {
    unsafe {
        match msg {
            WM_CREATE => {

                // Create a click button
        
                // Retrieve the pointer to your state and store it in the window's user data
                SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, lparam.0 as isize);
                increase_and_print(hwnd);

                LRESULT(0)
            },
            WM_DESTROY => {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                LRESULT(0)
            },
            WM_COMMAND => {
                increase_and_print(hwnd);
                return LRESULT(0);
            },
            _ => DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam)
        }
    }
}
```

The counter is initialized to 1, then increased to 2 in WM_CREATE msg. I expect it prints 3 after clicking the button (i.e. WM_COMMAND msg was called)
Output in console

```
GetWindowLongPtrW: 359815702944
counter: 2
GetWindowLongPtrW: 359815702944
thread 'main' panicked at 'misaligned pointer dereference: address must be a multiple of 0x4 but is 0xb', apps\counter\src\main.rs:73:9
```

[Complete code](https://gist.github.com/dcb9/fbd972e26da0ec703d95df6c83acf304)

Comment: Why do you call `GetWindowLongPtrW` twice? The second one could be simply `let ptr = ptr as *mut Box<Counter>;` (that's probably not what causes the problem, but it would make sure that `GetWindowLongPtrW` doesn't return a different value the second time…)

Comment: On second thought, why do you even have a `Box` at this point? It should be `let ptr = ptr as *mut Counter;` since calling `Box::leak` removed the `Box` and left a bare reference.

Comment: There's literally *nothing* simple about writing a Windows application in Rust, regardless of how little you intend this application to be doing. The only code I've seen so far that gets this mostly right is Raph Levien's [win-win](https://github.com/raphlinus/win-win) implementation. The comments are particularly insightful.

Comment: Thanks @Jmb, as you said it just make sure that `GetWindowLongPtrW` always returns a same pointer. The `Box` is required here, if I remove the `Box` in ` GetWindowLongPtrW(parent, GWLP_USERDATA) as *mut Box<Counter>;`, I cloud not get the initial value 1.

Comment: If you need the `Box` to get the initial value 1, then that means you probably really need `let ptr = *(ptr as *const *mut Counter);` (I don't know `GetWindowLongPtrW`, or really any of the Windows API, but casting to a `Box` here is just plain wrong since the value you passed to `CreateWindowExW` is _not_ a `Box`, so there's no reason for Windows to give you one back).

Comment: BTW, you might want to trace `lparam` when you call `CreateWindowExW` and `SetWindowLongPtrW` to make sure that the value you retrieve with `GetWindowLongPtrW` is what you think it is.

Comment: `GetWindowLongPtrW` always returns the same pointer, you can see this in the output of my post.

Comment: Yes `GetWindowLongPtrW` always returns the same pointer, but is that the pointer that you passed to `CreateWindowExW`?

Comment: It is the one I passed to `CreateWindowExW`, the output is the evidence, it prints 2 in the first time the `increase_and_print` function is called.

Comment: Actually the fact that `let ptr = ptr as *mut Counter;` doesn't work proves that it is _not_ the pointer that you passed to `CreateWindowExW`, but instead a pointer to a structure that starts with that pointer, which you would see if you printed the original pointer. As evidenced in the answer you posted, it is actually a pointer to a `CREATESTRUCTW` struct whose `lpCreateParams` field contains the pointer you passed. By chance `lpCreateParams` happens to be the first field of the struct, which is why casting to a `Box` appeared to work.

Answer (score 0):

I search for apps created by windows-rs on GitHub, finally I got this [robmikh/minesweeper-rs windows.rs](https://github.com/robmikh/minesweeper-rs/blob/8a8aa8bb127d961264b1f69368292d363bb66aa0/src/window.rs#L144-L156C8). It's totally what I was looking for.

Set counter to User data

```rust
let cs = lparam.0 as *const CREATESTRUCTW;
let counter = (*cs).lpCreateParams as *mut Counter;
SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, counter as _);
```

Retrieve counter and update its value

```rust
unsafe {
    let counter_ptr = GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA) as *mut Counter;
    if let Some(c) = counter_ptr.as_mut() {
        c.counter += 1;
        println!("counter: {}", c.counter);
    }
}
```

As I am new to Rust, I would be grateful if somebody could explain this in detail.

Comment: When you register a window class, the system allocates additional memory for every `HWND` created. `Get|SetWindowLongPtr` accesses that extra memory by index. The `GWLP_USERDATA` constant refers to a pointer-sized memory location that is being used to store a pointer to `Counter`. [`as_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.as_mut) performs a null-pointer check and returns `Some(&'a T)` for a non-null pointer to `T`.